# Does "instanceof Void" always return false?

Tags: java, generics, void, instanceof

Can this method return `true` somehow?

```
public static <T> boolean isVoid(T t)
{
    return t instanceof Void;
}
```

Comment: how do you call this method? can you give some examples?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this test? There must be some story behind all of this.

Comment: @Hovercraft I just like these tricky behavoirs beside I want to know more about "Void"

Comment: +1 for ridiculousness

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, but I'm sure that isn't really useful:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Constructor c = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
    c.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(c.newInstance(null) instanceof Void);
}
```

A `Void` class can't be instantiated so normally your code wouldn't require to deal with `Void` instances. The above code snippet is just an example of what havoc you can unleash when using reflection... ;-)

Comment: +1 very nice! btw, you just use `c.newInstance()` (don't need the `null` param)

Comment: +1 The only Class prevented from creating via Reflection is Class.

Comment: This is why if you want to make sure no one ever instantiates a class (e.g. library) you not only need to make the constructor private, but also make that constructor throw an exception. I'd recommend UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: @Sanjary T. Sharma Ah, "QFT".equals( "Quoted for Truth" )?

Comment: The equivalent code works without requiring anything complex in Scala: `().isInstanceOf[Unit] == true`

Answer (score 6):

I fail to see why you would check if a value is an instance of `void` (or `Void`) since, like said nth times, cannot be instanciated, or even extended without hacking with reflexion. However, for a more useful situation, if you want to know if a given `Class` is of a void type, you would not use `instanceof` and your method parameter would be of type `Class<?>` instead. A test case would be :

```
public class VoidCheckTest {

    public static void main(String...args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Class<VoidCheckTest> c = VoidCheckTest.class;

        Method m = c.getMethod("main", String[].class);

        System.out.println(m.getReturnType().getName() + " = " + isVoid(m.getReturnType()));        
    }

    private static boolean isVoid(Class<?> t) {
        return Void.class.isAssignableFrom(t) || void.class.equals(t);
    }
}
```

which would output

```
void = true
```

There might other use cases for this method, but I don't see any other right now.

Answer (score 3):

No:

```
Constructor<Void> cv = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor(); 
cv.setAccessible(true); 
Void v = cv.newInstance(); 
System.out.println(v instanceof Void); //-> true
```

Answer (score 2):

No. To make it return true you have to call it and pass an argument of type `Void`. But the constructor of class Void is private, so you cannot call it. Moreover, this class is final, so you cannot even extend it. Thus you cannot create an instance of class `Void`. But it is needed to make your method to return true.

BTW: If you really want to do it, call the constructor of `Void` by reflection. But I can think about this as a system abuse exercise. Good luck.